# On the Lipschitz continuity of a product of positive function and identity mapping

Tags: calculus, lipschitz-functions

Let $g:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a positive and continuous function and $C\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a nonempty compact set. Is the mapping
$$
G(x):=\frac{x}{g(x)}
$$
is Lipschitz continuous on $C$, i.e., there exists $L>0$ such that
$$
\|G(x)-G(y)\|\leq L\|x-y\|\quad \forall x,y\in C.
$$
**My attempt.** If $g$ is Lipschitz continuous on $C$ then $G$ is also Lipschitz continuous on $C$.
Indeed, since $g$ is Lipschitz continuous on $C$, there exits $l>0$ such that
$$
|g(x)-g(y)|\leq l\|x-y\| \quad \forall x,y\in C.
$$
Since $C$ is bounded, there exists $R>0$ such that
$$
\|x\|\leq C\quad \forall x\in C.
$$
Since $C$ is bounded and $g$ is continuous on $C$, by the Weierstrass theorem, there exist $m>0$ such that
$$
g(x)\geq m \quad \forall x\in C.
$$
For every $x,y\in C$ we have
\begin{eqnarray}
\|G(x)-G(y)\|&=&\left\|\frac{x}{g(x)}-\frac{y}{g(y)}\right\|\\
&=&\left\|\frac{x}{g(x)}-\frac{y}{g(x)}+\frac{y}{g(x)}-\frac{y}{g(y)}\right\|\\
&\leq&\left\|\frac{x}{g(x)}-\frac{y}{g(x)}\right\|+\left\|\frac{y}{g(x)}-\frac{y}{g(y)}\right\|\\
&=&\frac{\left\|x-y\right\|}{g(x)}+\frac{\|y\|}{g(x)g(y)}|g(x)-g(y)|\\
&\leq&\left(\frac{m+rl}{m^2}\right)\|x-y\|.
\end{eqnarray}
Hence, $G$ is Lipschitz continuous on $C$ with Lipschitz constant 
$$
L=\frac{m+rl}{m^2}.
$$
Thank you for all kind help and support.

Comment: you need $g$ to be Lipschitz for the proof to work.

Comment: Yes. I would like to know whether $G$ is Lipschitz continuous when $g$ is merely continuous (not Lipschitz continuous).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider 
$$ g(x) = 
\begin{cases}
1, & x = 0, \\
1 + x \sin(x^{-2}), & 0 < |x| \le \frac12, \\
1 + \frac{1}{2} \sin (\frac{1}{4}), & x > \frac{1}{2}, \\
1 - \frac{1}{2} \sin (\frac{1}{4}), & x < \frac{-1}2.
\end{cases}
$$ 
Then, $g$ is positive.
Further, $G$ is not differentiable at $0$ and singular around $0$. Thus, $G$ is not Lipschitz continuous on any compact containing $0$.

Comment: Note that $g$ is a continuous function.

Comment: @Blind: $g$ can be continuously extended to $0$ with $g(0) = 1$.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Could you explain clearer why $g(x)$ is a positive function?

Comment: $g$ is positive near $0$. As $x\sin(x^{-2}) \to 0$ for $x\to 0$.

Comment: Here $g$ is positive on the whole space $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: You could just make $g$ constant outside $[-1/2, 1/2]$.

Comment: How can we check $G$ is not differentiable at $0$ and $g$ is not Lipschitz continuous.

Comment: @Blind differentiate $G$ at $x\ne 0$ and take the limit for $x\to 0$.

Comment: I have the opposite question: Suppose $G(x) = g(x).x \in \mathbb{R}$ on a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $g(x): \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. $g(x)$ is bounded. We know nothing more about g(x). But it is given that $G(x)$ is Lipschitz. Then what additional properties does it imply for $g(x)$?